# Java Date "before" method dont exist

Tags: java, date, netbeans

I have imported import java.util.*; import java.util.Date; but NetBeans shows that method "before" dont exist. Data2 is taken from the input, "current" from current day.

```
    Date now = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" ); 
    String current =  formatter.format( now );
    String data2 = data.getText(); 
    boolean result = data2.before(current);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data2` is a String. `before` is a method of `Date` class.

You should parse `data2` into a `Date` instance and call `date2.before(now)` (assuming `date2` is a `Date`).

Comment: So even if i add String data3 =  formatter.format( data2 );  and boolean result = data3.before(current); error still shows

Comment: @JanuszBieraszewski Of course it wouldn't change anything. `data3` is still a String, and has no `before` method.

Comment: I parsed and 'trycatched' both, works fine, thanks

Answer (score 2):

`before` is a method from `Date` datatype. You are using `String`. `Data2` is of `String` datatype.

Example of using `before()`:

```
Date date = new Date(11, 5, 21);
Date date2 = new Date(15, 1, 21);
boolean before = date2.before(date);
System.out.println("Date 2 is before date: " + before);
```